# getting cannot get route error when using express.router

Tags: express, express-router

whenever i try to access my /products/addproduct, it always show CANNOT GET /products/addproduct no matter whether i access the route using the button in addproduct.ejs or normally.

my file structure

index js
routes
----products js
views
----addproduct ejs
----index ejs
----login ejs

index.js

```js
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser')

const products = require('./routes/products')
const { isBuffer } = require('util')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieparser())
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}))
app.use('products', products)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    passowrd: "",
    database: "info"
})

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err)
    console.log(err)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.loggedin === "true")
        res.render('index')
    else
        res.redirect("/login")
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.loggedin === "true")
        res.redirect('/')
    else
        res.render('login', {exists: ''})
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? and password = ?"
    db.query(sql, [email, password], (err, result) => {
        if(err) { 
            return console.log(err)
        }
        if(result.length > 0) {
            req.session.loggedin = "true"
            res.redirect('/')
        }
        else {
            res.render('login', {exists: 'wrong email or password'})
        }
    })    
})

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
})
```

products.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/addproduct', (req, res) => {
    res.render('addproduct')
})

module.exports = router
```

addproducts.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="addproduct" method="POST">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Product Name">
            <br>
            <input name="desc" type="text" placeholder="Description">
            <br>
            <label> Category </label>  
            <select name="category">  
                <option value = "electronics">electronics</option>  
                <option value = "sports">sports</option>  
                <option value = "fashion">fashion</option>  
            </select>  
            <input name="price" type="number" placeholder="price">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
            <br>
            <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            <span> <%= exists %> </span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Home Page </h1>
        <a href="/products/addproduct"> Add a product </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try put `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` before `app.use('products', products)`

Comment: that did not work.